# Grails internationaliization with custom bundles

Tags: grails, internationalization, gsp

My Grails (2.4.2) app was created with a bunch of "default/standard" resource bundles:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        i18n/
            messages.properties
            messages_fr.properties
```

I would now like to create my own "custom" resource bundle, that is, define properties in a file outside of these standard `messages*.properties` files that `myapp` was created with.

According to the i18n documentation, all bundles need to be prefixed with `messages` and suffixed `.properties`. So I added two new props files, one for English and one for French:

```
myapp/
    grails-app/
        i18n/
            messages.properties
            messages_fr.properties
            messages_myapp.properties
            messages_myapp_fr.properties
```

For one, I'm not 100% sure I'm interpreting the docs correctly. So if anything about my 2 new props files jumps out at you as being incorrect, please start by letting me know!

Having said that, in all the example from those docs, I don't see where you specify the bundle to use. All of the examples look like this:

```
<g:message code="fizz.buzz.foo" />
```

But what if I have a `fizz.buzz.foo` property defined in both `messages_blah.properties` and `messages_bar.properties`?

So I ask: **How do I add my own custom resource bundles, and how do I properly refer to them from inside a GSP?**

Comment: The files do not need to start with `messages`; in my current project (Grails 2.4.4) I have for example `domain.properties` and `navigation.properties` (together with their translated versions, e.g. `domain_de.properties`) and they are being picked up just fine by Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you have to understand what Grails (well, Spring really) is doing to accomplish this.

You are on the right path with the multiple files. What you have outlined there matches the documentation and will work.

However, under the covers what is really being done is they are being combined into a single bundle (per language). So there is no need to tell Grails/Spring which bundle to use.

Finally, what happens when the same key is defined multiple times? The first one matched wins. I seem to recall that the order in which the bundles are combined is in file name order, though you should be able to test this pretty quickly.

Hope this helps, and best of luck!

Comment: As always, thank you @Joshua Moore (+1) - however `<g:message code="fizz.buzz.foo" />` is not resolving, instead "fizz.buzz.foo" is being rendered as plaintext in the HTML. Any deas?

Comment: Meant to say "ideas" above, not "deas".  (Any ideas)?

Comment: Yep, try not using an underscore in your file names (with the exception of the required one for the language) e.g. myapp.properties vs messages_myapp.properties, plus make sure you stop your application and run a `clean` when you add/remove new files. Here is just some further info: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/grails-goodness-splitting-i18n-message.html

Comment: You're welcome, and kudos for reading the documentation first!